# Rails: NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I am following this tutorial in YT:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyjzi837wME&list=PLWqjhA7WxVW6L7AWzQElmYfXV3NUv_Lbs&index=1

```
        def update 
            airline = Airline.find_by(slug: params[:slug])

            if airline.update(airline_params)
                render json: AirlineSerializer.new(airline, options).serialized_json
            else 
                render json: {error: "airline not "}, status: 422
            end
        end
```

But I am getting this error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This means there's no airline in your DB with that slug.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I am quite sure there is this airline.

Comment: The database disagrees with you, evidently. Maybe `params[:slug]` does not hold the value you think it does.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, ok, I probably made a mistake somewhere

Comment: managed to spot my mistake, rails is painful

Comment: only if you fight it. Rails is full of conventions and you're expected to do things a certain way. If you do that, life is easy and you can make functional apps within hours/days. https://dhh.dk/2012/rails-is-omakase.html

Answer (score 2):

In controllers you almost always want to use `find` or `find_by!` so that an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception is raised and you bail early instead of getting a nil error:

```
def update 
  airline = Airline.find_by!(slug: params[:slug])
  if airline.update(airline_params)
    render json: AirlineSerializer.new(airline, options).serialized_json
  else 
    render json: { errors: airline.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
  end
end
```

After all if the record can't even be found there is no reason to continue processing - which is something the tutorial author didn't consider or test for.

This exception is rescued by Rails by default which sends a 404 response but you can override it on a per controller basis by using rescue_from:

```ruby
class AirlinesController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

  # ...

  private
 
  def not_found
    render json: { error: "Oh noes" }, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

On a side note `params[:slug]` is a bit of an antipattern. Your routes should just stick with the conventional `/airlines/:id`. `:id` in this case just means a *unique identifier* for the resource and not the *id* column. This avoids the need to refactor if you want to look records up by id or slug.

There are also some other problems with the tutorial code:

- Authentication is opt-in as evidenced by `before_action :authenticate, only: %i[create update destroy]`. Use a opt-out secure by default approach instead so that you don't inadvertantly leave security holes. You do this by adding `before_action :authenticate` in your `ApiController` (or whatever the base class is) and then using `skip_before_action :authenticate, ...` to opt out on endpoints that should not require authentication.
- There is no validation of slugs and no guarentee of uniqueness for either the slug or name in the form of unique indexes. Just validating the name doesn't actually guarentee the uniqueness of the slug as the name can be changed but the slug is generated when the record is first created.
- `parameterize` is a quite naive solution to the problem of slugging. For real world use cases you need a library like [stringex](https://github.com/rsl/stringex). Or use [FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) if you want to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted my mistake in following the tutorial.  The code in the route should be as below:

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :airlines, param: :slug
      resources :reviews, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
```

Instead I have put `resources :airlines, params: :slug` with an s in the param.

So I am not very sure why there is no warning about this error when I tried to run it.

Comment: As indicated in my answer the tutorial author didn't even consider the scenario where the record can't be found. When you access the params it does not raise an error if you try to get a non-existant key. So you're doing `Airline.find_by(slug: nil)` which gives you a whole lot of nothing - this shouldn't be allowed to happen. Rails won't warn you if don't use the correct methods.